# If $E, F \subset [0, 1]$, $m(E), m(F) > 0$, and $E_n = \{x \in [0, 1] : nx \bmod 1 \in E\}$, show $m(F\cap E_n) > 0$ for sufficiently large $n$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $E \subset [0, 1]$ has positive Lebesgue measure and let $E_n = \{x \in [0, 1] : nx \bmod 1 \in E\}$. If $F \subset [0, 1]$ has positive Lebesgue measure, show that so does $F \cap E_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

To be honest, I have no idea how I should approach this question. I can't even see how the various $E_n$'s are related to each other. As $E$ and $F$ both have positive Lebesgue measure, they have points of Lebesgue density one, but I don't see how that could help. Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$ k\cdot\mu(F) + \mu(E) > 1, $$
then the measure of 
$$ k F = \{k \cdot f\!\!\!\!\pmod{1}:\,f\in F\} $$
is just $k\cdot \mu(F)$, hence $k F$ intersects $E$ in a set of positive measure.

But this is the same as saying that $F\cap E_k$ has a positive measure.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why $\mu(kF) = k\mu(F)$ if $k\mu(F) + \mu(E) > 1$. Surely this can't be true if $k > \frac{1}{\mu(F)}$.

Comment: Think to $F$ as a disjoint union of intervals on $S^1$. In such a case, $\mu(k\cdot F)=\max(k\cdot \mu(F)),1)$. The same holds here.